# What is an extremal horizon?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, event-horizon, holographic-principle, black-hole-thermodynamics

In the contest of holography and thermodynamics, what is an extremal horizon? I am going through a paper by Hartnoll, Santos - *Disordered Horizons: Holography of randomly disordered fixed points.* They talk about IR being described by an extremal horizon with the critical exponent tending to infinity.

Comment: They seem to be interested in the zero temperature limit. Maybe it is the even horizon of the extremal black hole in $AdS_3$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the term in the context of a Reissner-Nordstrom black hole? It's similar in this case, and the extremal black hole is indeed the zero-temperature limit of a non-extremal one.

Comment: Yes, I understand now.